# Hunter Sentinel LED Ceiling Fan/lights with remote: lights will just turn off then turn back on randomly

Tags: ceiling-fan, led, flashing

Installed 2 of them in separate rooms on separate circuits. After 10 minutes of the light being on (fan is off), the light will shut off and then immediately turn back on. I turned off the dimming feature with no success. No other appliances are turning on. And they will blink independently of each other. The pattern of the shut off can be as rapidly as every 30 seconds; other times it may be 20 minutes. I installed the bulbs that came with the fixture.

Comment: Can you try different bulbs, maybe only one or two. If possible make them tungsten and see if the problem goes away. I am thinking there are some transients on the power line that cause this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you checked the [URL listed in the manual](https://s7d5.scene7.com/is/content/HunterFan/98000-03-411pdf), "If you have multiple remotes or multiple remote-controlled fans installed on the same circuit breaker and you are experiencing interference or faulty operation of your remote controls, please go to [www.HunterFan.com/FAQs](http://www.HunterFan.com/FAQs) and click “How do I properly install multiple remote-controlled fans?” If that link does not work, try [downloading that guide directly](https://assets.hunterfan.com/is/content/HunterFan/Multiple-Platform-Remotes-English-pdf).
2. Is there excessive RF noise on the AC mains?
3. Are there other devices in your home or a nearby neighbor using the same remote control frequencies?